# encoding while importing csv to xls via powershell

Tags: excel, powershell, csv, encoding

I use this code (found somewhere) to convert csv to xls. It works perfectly when there is no national characters.
When I am trying to convert csv file with encoding ISO 2859-2 I have some text errors. Any idea how to deal with this character set in this script?

```
### Set input and output path
$inputCSV = "C:\tmp\test.CSV"
$outputXLSX = "C:\tmp\test.xls"

### Create a new Excel Workbook with one empty sheet which name is the file
$excel = New-Object -ComObject excel.application
$workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Add(1)
$worksheet = $workbook.worksheets.Item(1)
$worksheet.name = "$((GCI $inputCSV).basename)"

### Build the QueryTables.Add command
### QueryTables does the same as when clicking "Data » From Text" in Excel
$TxtConnector = ("TEXT;" + $inputCSV)
$Connector = $worksheet.QueryTables.add($TxtConnector,$worksheet.Range("A1"))
$query = $worksheet.QueryTables.item($Connector.name)

### Set the delimiter ( , or ; ) according to your regional settings
$query.TextFileOtherDelimiter = $Excel.Application.International(5)

### Set the format to delimited and text for every column
### A trick to create an array of 2s is used with the preceding comma
### this options don't seems necessary
$query.TextFileParseType  = 1
$query.TextFileColumnDataTypes = ,2 * $worksheet.Cells.Columns.Count
### change decimal separator as "." (can be ",")
$query.TextFileDecimalSeparator = "."
$query.AdjustColumnWidth = 1

### Execute & delete the import query
# using my_output avoid having an outuput that display true
$my_output = $query.Refresh()
$query.Delete()

### Save & close the Workbook as XLS.
$Workbook.SaveAs($outputXLSX,56)
$excel.Quit()
```

Comment: Can you provide the errors please.

Comment: I would suggest [converting the CSV file to UTF-8](http://www.powershelladmin.com/wiki/Convert_from_most_encodings_to_utf8_with_powershell). If resulting Unicode will be broken too, the issue has nothing to do with Excel (and it's probably the input file encoding being broken).

Comment: It is not an error, these are just random characters used when there is no proper sign in character set which is used by default in excel. I'll try converting this csv to UTF8 first.

Comment: Converting to UTF8 didn't help.

When I open this CSV in excel I see errors in text like these: "Wła¶ciciel"  "S±d ".
To see text correctly in excel I have to import as a text with encoding set to ISO 8859-2.

How to do it in this powershell script?

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge there is no way to do that in Excel. This is workaround, exporting to UnicodeText which is basically TAB delimited csv.

Export-ExcelCSV.ps1

```
param(
    [string] $Path
)

if (!(Test-Path $Path)) { throw Path not found: $Path }

$Path = Resolve-Path $Path
$excel = New-Object -COM "Excel.Application"
if (!($excel)) {throw "Can not create Excel COM object" }

$workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Open($Path)
$worksheets = $workbook.Worksheets


$base_name = $path -replace '.xlsx$'
$worksheets | % {
    $sheet = $_
    $csv_name = $base_name + '_' + $sheet.name + '.csv'
    if (Test-Path $csv_name) {  rm $csv_name }
    $sheet.SaveAs($csv_name, [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat]::xlUnicodeText) ; # xlCSVWindows, xlCSV, xlUnicodeText
}

$workbook.Saved = $true
$workbook.close()
$excel.quit()
#[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($workbook) > $null
#[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($excel) > $null

ps excel | kill     #for some reason Excel stays, this will also kill any other running excels not related to this script.
ls *.csv | % { (Get-Content $_) -replace '\t',',' | Set-Content $_ -Encoding utf8 }
```